Testing for Gaussian Mixtures
Suppose I observe data from a univariate distribution $\mathcal{D}$ with zero mean, and unit variance. We know that either $\mathcal{D} = \mathcal{D}_0 = \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is standard Gaussian or $\mathcal{D} = \mathcal{D}_1 = \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{N}(\mu, 1 - \mu^2) + \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{N}(-\mu, 1 - \mu^2)$ is a Gaussian mixture for some $\mu \in (0,1)$. Depending on $\mu$, how many samples $n$ from $\mathcal{D}$ do I need to distinguish between the two distributions with high probability, say $1-\delta$? That is, I would like to have $n = n(\delta, \mu)$ such that some decision function $\phi$ satisfies
$$P(\phi(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 1 | \mathcal{D} = \mathcal{D}_0) + P(\phi(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 0 | \mathcal{D} = \mathcal{D}_1) \le \delta$$
I presume that higher-moment tests would be the way to go, but are they optimal? Also, I don't know of any guarantees for them.

it is going to be a function of distance between means of mixture components and of mixture covariances.  This book goes into it in some detail: https://a.co/d/dkegwk8 aka https://archive.org/details/finitemixturemod00geof . I think you are looking in ch1 about identifiability and estimation.
